# #14 in a chord?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

I have a chord consisting of G, B, D, F, B, D#, F# and makes the polychord B/G7. The G7 at the bottom resolves to a C chord, and the top B chord shifts chromatically upwards into a C chord as well. Is there any symbol other than a polychord to express that one chord, e.g. "G7(b13,#14) or G7(b13,b15)?

Comment: If your main question is, "what else can I call this chord," consider changing your title to reflect that.

Comment: @mawcsco, I tend to like the title as is because the #14 is highly specific, which improves future search-ability.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Your question is "#14 in a chord?" Which I've answered. Your secondary question, "is there any symbol other than a polychord to express that one chord," had also been answered. If you have additional unanswered questions, I recommend editing your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 9, 11, and 13 intervals used as tensions. In a G7 cord, 9 is A, 11 is C, and 13 is E. The F in this chord is technically a flat 7. F# is the major 7.

If a 14 interval existed, it would be F, which is already covered by the 7. If a 15 interval existed, it'd be G, your root. The distance, diatonically, between a 7 and the root of a scale is a half step. #14/b15 can't possibly represent a note because it is enharmonically equivalent to your root, G (#14) or your 7th (b15). Using #14/b15 adds unnecessary complexity with no benefit.

Writing the chord as B/G7 gives musicians information about how you expect the harmonies to play out in performance.  You are expecting lower harmony to be G7, and you are expecting upper harmony to be B. It's useful and concise.

If, however, you don't have the arranging expectation of harmonic spread, or your are writing for a single instrument like guitar, then it might be expressed differently.

- G is your root
- B is your third
- D is your 5th, but it might be omitted
- F is your b7
- B is already your third
- D# is a b13
- F# makes things complicated because now your chord has both the 7 and flat 7. Suddenly, your chord sounds less like a dominant 7, and more like a maj7 with tensions.

Let's rework the chord to achieve the same sound.

- G is your root
- B is your third
- D is your 5th, but let's omit it.
- Eb (D#) is your flat 13
- E# (F) is your #13; this is a little unusual.
- F# is your major 7th

So, we can write it:
Gmaj7(b13,#13)

Your chord, without inversions, will have the notes G, B, Eb, F, F#. We've dropped the D because it isn't necessary and detracts from the tension of the b13. But without inversions, there will be some dissonance. Try pulling the maj7 down near the root like this, G, F#, B, Eb, F. If you're playing on a piano, use shell voicing to spread it out a bit.

Here are a few other ways of labeling the same chord:

- G+7(#9)
- G7(#9#5)
- Bmaj7(b5)/G
- Bmaj7(#11#5)/G
- Bmaj7(#5b5)/G
- Bmaj7(b13b5)/G
- F7(b5sus4)/G
- F9(b5sus4)/G

Comment: Thanks for sharing your expertise! It sounds like you recommend against using the notation #14 or b15. I think those two were mainly given as examples of possible alternatives. I see the main question here as being: "what else could I call this chord?" I'm interested in your thoughts on that. Do you recommend writing this chord as anything besides B/G7?

Comment: @jdjazz I've updated my answer with more info about your chord.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very interesting theoretical perspective. +1 for the rigorous approach! I do wonder, though, how the function factors in. I really like the approach of this answer and think there's some really valuable insight into how to analyze polychords. But in this case, we do have V-I, and the G resolves to C. For that reason, I'm inclined to call the G chord G7 rather than GΔ7(b13 #13). I don't mean to discount the awesome theory you're describing--I just wonder if it applies to this particular scenario where we have V-I movement.

Comment: (Also, this isn't my Q, but I'm very interested in the answer, since I wouldn't know what to call this chord except B/G7.)

Comment: The labeling of a chord doesn't determine its function. Lots of chords can have a dominant function and aren't a "dominant 7" chord. Take the triad G, for example. No F or F#in that chord, but it still resolves to C. Gmaj7 is still a V chord, just like G7 and it serves the same function in the key of C. The tensions in the chord only serve to enhance this function by giving it a richer dominant quality. Further, F# is the tritone to C, and that instability is important to the feeling of resolution.

Comment: Do you agree that G7 has a stronger dominant function than GΔ7? To my ear (and I think in Western tradition), the F in G7 resolves more strongly to the 3rd of Cmaj than the F# in GΔ7. If we're notating a chord, I think part of the job is to reflect the correct function. If there's ambiguity and both G7 and GΔ7 are choices, then I think the traditional dominant function can be a determining factor in how to notate.

Comment: Gmaj7 is a V chord, but it hardly serves the same function as G7. I rarely if ever hear the V chord modified as a maj7 chord. Also, G7 is arguably a stronger resolution because of its tritone between B and F, which is often considered unstable, collapsing into C and E respectively. Whereas F♯ jumping to C, while a melodic interval of a tritone, isn't considered to exhibit dominant function. Gmaj7 actually tends to establish part of a G major tonality, since that and D major are the only two places that Gmaj7 is diatonic. Traditionally, maj7 chords aren't often nondiatonic compared to 7 chords.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the best way to write this is with your polychord notation. That's unambiguous and easy to read, plus it shows exactly how the chord resolves. What more could you want from a chord symbol? The only other reasonable solution would be to completely reject chord symbols and write out all the notes on a staff, which I assume you've already ruled out.

I strongly dislike the use ♯13 or ♯14. Those aren't part of the vocabulary of most musicians, and they would definitely lead to confusion on the bandstand. If you want to write crazy extentsions like ♯13 and ♯14, I'm not going to stop you, but do so knowing that you may lose some friends in the process :)

*You're probably already aware of this, but note that a true polychord symbol should have a horizontal vinculum rather than the diagonal "slash" which is used to represent slash chords.*

Comment: @Lars, I think this is the correct answer. The best way to notate the chord is as a polychord. The point about using well-known notation is extremely valuable. A jazz musician will be able to decipher the harmony and improvisation techniques more quickly from B/G7 than from G7(b13 b15).

Answer (score 1):

The notation for jazz chords is a completely arbitrary system.

There is no *musical* justification for the assumption that all chords are constructed from stacks of thirds.

There is no *musical* justification for the arbitrary assumption that the 7th is part of the basic chord but the 9th, 11th, and 13th are somehow different and should be called "tensions."

So within those arbitrary rules for constructing chord symbols, the label "#14" doesn't make any sense.

Whether or not it makes any *musical* sense in a given context is a completely different question.